# Como adicionar 30 dias em uma data no LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite senhores, eu sou iniciante em programação e estou com dificuldades em adicionar 30 dias em uma determinada data.
Estou fazendo um laço de repetição para gerar como se fosse boletos no sistema, quando o usuário informar determinada data e a quantidade de parcelas da compra o sistema automaticamente divide o valor pela quantidade de parcelas e salva no banco aquelas parcelas já com os valores exatos. só que estou encontrando dificuldades em adicionar sempre 30 dias a cada entrada no laço de repetição.
Como por exemplo :
A compra foi dia 18/05 e o código adicionaria mais 30 dias a essa data na próxima volta do laço, então a data salva ficaria 17/06.

```
$numBoletos = $request->qtd_parcelas-1;
    $vencimentoParcela = $request->data_compra;
    for ($contador = 1; $contador <= $request->qtd_parcelas; $contador++) {
        $vencimentoParcela = $vencimentoParcela;
        $boletos_crediario = new Boleto;
        $boletos_crediario->os = $request->os;
        $boletos_crediario->nome_cliente = $request->nome_cliente;
        $boletos_crediario->data_vencimento = $vencimentoParcela;
        $boletos_crediario->num_boleto = $request->qtd_parcelas - $numBoletos;
        $boletos_crediario->valor_boleto = $request->valor_compra / $request->qtd_parcelas;
        $boletos_crediario->save();
        $vencimentoParcela = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime('$vencimentoParcela')));
        $numBoletos--;
    }
```

[image: Um exemplo de como esta salvando no banco as datas]

As datas no banco ficam salvas dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua linha ...

```php
$vencimentoParcela = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime('$vencimentoParcela')));
```

... você está passando o segundo parâmetro da função `date` um `boolean`, e não uma data.
Isso pois na chamada a [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php), você precisa OU passar como o segundo parâmetro, um inteiro que será interpretado como um `timestamp`; OU não passar este parâmetro, o que irá fazer o PHP interpretar com o timestamp do momento da execução. Do contrário, o resultado será `FALSE`.

Com isso a função não está conseguindo fazer o cálculo correto.

No seu caso, a variável `$vencimentoParcela` já é uma data, então você poderia simplesmente chamar assim:

```php
$vencimentoParcela = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', $vencimentoParcela));
```

No código abaixo, um exemplo de como você pode gerar as datas conforme mencionado acima:

```php
$n_parcelas = 5;
$data_compra =  strtotime('2022-05-19 0:0:0');
var_dump($data_compra);//saída -> int(1652918400)
//abaixo está sendo chamado strtotime em cima de um valor que já é 
//um timestamp. Isso resulta em FALSE
//e reproduz a situção que causa o erro nas datas
$result = strtotime($data_compra); 
var_dump($result);  //bool(false)
$primeiro_vencimento = $vencimento = strtotime('2022-05-25 0:0:0');
echo "Primeiro vencimento: " . date('d/m/Y', $primeiro_vencimento) . "\n";
foreach(range(1, $n_parcelas) as $parcela){
    //se aqui for utilizada a variável 'result' acima, 
    //todas as datas serão de janeiro/1970
    $vencimento = strtotime('+30 days', $vencimento);
    echo "Parcela $parcela vencerá em: " . date('d/m/Y', $vencimento). "\n";
}
```

```
int(1652918400)
bool(false)
Primeiro vencimento: 25/05/2022
Parcela 1 vencerá em: 24/06/2022
Parcela 2 vencerá em: 24/07/2022
Parcela 3 vencerá em: 23/08/2022
Parcela 4 vencerá em: 22/09/2022
Parcela 5 vencerá em: 22/10/2022
```

Comment: Perfeito, Consegui resolver com sua resposta, muito obrigado

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar.